# grails how to have slash ("/") in the request parameters

Tags: grails

I have the following controller/action "FilesController:browse" and the following URL mapping:

```
 "/files/browse/$path"(controller: 'Files', action: 'browse')
```

How can I allow this path to accept to accept forward slash "/"? For example:

```
  /files/browse/somedirectory/somefile.jpg
```

and the `path` parameter becomes `/somedirectory/somefile.jpg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#mappingWildcards) you can do:

```
"/files/browse/$path**"(controller: 'Files', action: 'browse')
```